# My ASP.NET REST app returning a 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

My REST service (ASP.NET running on Azure as an AppService) ran fine until a recent change that was minimal. If I go to https://update.windward.net/ it returns fine. But a POST to https://update.windward.net/Service/version returns a 400.

I'm 99% certain my service is not being called, that it happens before then. Here's the service entry points:

```
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
        public string GetTest()
        {
            return $"Windward update REST service version {AssmVersion}; " +
                   $"Newest AutoTag version: {ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AutoTagVersion"]}; " +
                   $"Most recent exception {mostRecentTime:G} : {mostRecentError}";
        }


        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Service/version", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        public XmlElement GetVersion(XmlElement root)
        {

            try
            {
//...
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("GetVersion", ex);
                mostRecentError = $"GetVersion({root.Name}): {ex.Message}";
                mostRecentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I'm having trouble getting the logging to work so all I have for debugging is the mostRecentError string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more interesting thing for those that have a similar problem - is how I found the issue.

I used [the Azure diagnostic tool described here (including how to use it)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/06/06/app-service-diagnostics-profiling-an-asp-net-web-app-on-azure-app-service/). From that I discovered that my service method was being called, and in that code it was throwing an exception.

So item #1 - getting a 400 probably means your service is being called, but is throwing an exception.

And item #2, logging works, but the Azure tool is a lot better (at least in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you strip down the `RequestFormat`, `ResponseFormat` and `BodyStyle` from the attribute and change the `root` method parameter to `string` to see if the requests are arriving at the method or not.

Once you establish that, try adding back the removed/changed code(one at a time), to see what affects the call to the method.

Hope it helps!